# Thin replacement for fat std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I'm trying to pack my object to 64 bytes (homegrown properties), and I need to save getter and setter member functions.

I really like std::function but is way big:

`sizeof(std::function<int(void)>)` gives 40 bytes (VS2017, x64).

I'm trying to figure out is there any thin version of `std::function` 16 bytes large and without extra allocations inside?

**Update:** Solution looks like this, it takes 16 bytes (x64) for two member functions. 
Member function pointers became template argument so they take nothing, stored just object pointer and vptr.

Thanks to @Yakk.

```
class Property
{
public:
    virtual ~Property() {}

    virtual QVariant value() const = 0;
    virtual void setValue(const QVariant& value) = 0;
};

template<typename TYPE,
         typename CLASS,
         TYPE(CLASS::*get)() const,
         void(CLASS::*set)(const TYPE &)>
class PropertyValue : public Property
{
public:
    PropertyValueGet() = delete;
    PropertyValueGet(PropertyValueGet const& ) = delete;
    PropertyValueGet& operator=(PropertyValueGet const& ) = delete;

    PropertyValueGet(CLASS* object) : m_object(object)  {}

    TYPE getValue() const {
        return (m_object->*get)();
    }

    void setValue(const TYPE& value) {
        (m_object->*set)(value);
    }

    // Property implementation
    //
    virtual QVariant value() const final {
        QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue<TYPE>(getValue());
        return v;
    }

    virtual void setValue(const QVariant& value) final {
        setValue(value.value<TYPE>());
    }

private:
    CLASS* m_object = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: You can make your own `std::function` replacement that has a `sizeof` of `sizeof(void *)`, but you can't do it without allocations. `std::function` can hold any callable object of the correct type which can have any size. You would need to limit functionality to only allow callable objects of a limited size.

Comment: You need at the very least - a pointer to the function; and a pointer to the object you want to call it on.  If you're willing to not use objects then you can skip one of those pointers; but otherwise under 16 just isn't possible (on a 64 bit machine)

Comment: This looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to store getters and setters?

Comment: also (in case that's what you want to do) `std::function` cannot be trivially serialized. E.g. you can't `memcpy`  it (or any trick)

Comment: 1. Yes, the very minimum is 16 bytes and it's ok.
2. It's not XY problem, I'm asking for solution
3. Making own simple std::function looks like solution, probably there is already one?

Comment: What, *exactly*, do you want to store in your `std::function`?  If you want to store a getter/setter with 10 mb of data in it, you aren't going to be able to store it in an 8 byte `std::function` clone with no "extra allocations", yet *`std::function` can store that*.

Comment: 2 Yakk, it's pointer to getters/setters in some object
 `std::function<TYPE(void)> m_getter;`

Comment: Need some time, trying to apply answers

Comment: @Serhiy You appear to have no idea what a `std::function` does or what it is.  Please stop referring to it as what you want.   You appear to want some kind of way to store *something* in a type you can invoke with `()`.  `std::function<TYPE()>` does this.  What I need to know is **EXACTLY** do you want to store in that type.  Actual **CODE** demonstrating the **EXACT** type of callable objects you want to store.  "getters/setters" -- those aren't C++ types.  Are you trying to say "member function pointers"?  With the this pointer bound, but no ownership over the object?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, you are right, I need "member function pointers" with this, with templated TYPE and with defined signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has clarified that the members used are fixed:

```
template<class T>
struct generic_property {
  virtual T getValue() const = 0;
  virtual void setValue(T const&) = 0;
protected:
  virtual ~generic_property() {}
};
template<class D, class T, void(D::*set)(T const&), T(D::*get)() const>
struct property:generic_property<T> {
    T getValue() const final {
        return (self->*get)();
    }
    void setValue(T const& t) final {
        (self->*set)(t);
    }
    property( D* s ):self(s) {}

// cannot usually safely copy/move/trivial:     
    property() = delete;
    property( property const& ) = delete;
    property& operator=( property const& ) = delete;
private:
    D* self = 0;
};

struct Bob {
    void setFoo( int const& i ) { std::cout << i << " set\n"; }
    int getFoo() const { std::cout << 42 << " get\n"; return 42; }
    property<Bob, int, &Bob::setFoo, &Bob::getFoo> foo;

    Bob():foo(this) {}
};
```

each `property` takes up 1 pointers worth of space (so 32 to 64 bits, or 4-8 bytes, depending on the bit-width of the OS).

Adding `virtual` and `generic_property<T>` makes it take up another pointer's worth of space.

[live example](https://ideone.com/TYMFZt).

We could type erase manually in `generic_property` instead of by virtual inheritance.

Comment: Yes, pointers to members became template arguments, the only member is object pointer. `struct property` has (will have) base class and kept in map by property name. `struct property` is not base for `Bob`. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5):

The type of `m_getter` is `decltype(m_getter)`.

Using `std::mem_fn` in Modern C++ is a bad idea - *lambda expressions* are a cleaner and more transparent (both to the developer and the compiler) way of binding arguments.

Stephan T. Lavavej, in the talk [“functional: What's New, And Proper Usage"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0), mentions some drawbacks of `std::bind` and `std::mem_fn` compared to lambdas:

[image: memfn problems #0]

[image: memfn problems #1]

[image: bind problems]

You should use a *lambda expression* instead. E.g.:

```
auto my_getter = [](Foo& foo){ return foo.getter(); };

Foo some_foo;
my_getter(some_foo);
```

or

```
Foo some_foo;
auto my_getter = [&some_foo](){ return some_foo.getter(); };

my_getter();
```

Comment: My bad :) -----

Comment: Ouch, text as images. Even though you probably only got it as images yourself.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: `[](object* x){ x->something(); }` ?

Comment: @KillzoneKid the same, but with `*` and `->`?

Comment: `std::mem_fn` has the advantage that you can call it with either `Foo*` or `Foo&` and it still works (which is useful approximately never). The lambda expression above can't do that, but `[](auto& obj) { return std::invoke(&Foo::getter, obj); }` would do it, assuming `getter` is not overloaded.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Splendid!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: agreed that it's not useful - you can probably simulate that with a generic lambda if you really wanted to anyway

Comment: @VittorioRomeo yeah I just edited the comment to do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely If only we could just pass `&Foo::getter`... something... something...

Answer (score 3):

`&Foo::getter` has a type, it is `TYPE(Foo::*)(void)`, which is *most likely* a smaller type than `std::function<TYPE(void)>`. Similarly `&Foo::setter` is a `void(Foo::*)(TYPE)`.

But you can get *even smaller*, by discarding the errant notion that getters and setters are encapsulation, with `&Foo::field`, which is a `TYPE Foo::*`.

```
template<typename T, typename C>
struct Property
{
    Property(T C::*member) : member(member) {}
    T & get(C & c) { return std::invoke(member, c); }
    void set(C & c, T & t) { std::invoke(member, c) = t; }
private:
    T C::* member;
}
```

Alternately accompanying an instance

```
template<typename T, typename C>
struct Property
{
    Property(T C::*member, C & instance) : member(member), instance(instance) {}
    T & get() { return std::invoke(member, instance); }
    void set(T & value) { std::invoke(member, instance) = value; }
private:
    T C::* member;
    C & instance;
}
```

Comment: N.B. those parentheses are redundant, the type is `TYPE Foo::*`

Comment: Thanks for the answer: it the example in `get` and `set` is used the same `member`, how is it possible, do I need two of them for get func and set func?

Comment: let's say you have `class Thing { int field; }`. You make a `Property<int, Thing> field_prop(&Thing::field)`, then `get` is the same as `return instance.field` and `set` is the same as `instance.field = value`

Comment: [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) unifies member access with calling a function. See the second bullet in the definition of `INVOKE`

Answer (score 2):

This is a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) answer, because doing this in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) is really annoying.

Here is a "simple" stateless view-only std::function.

```
// utility tag type for dispatching
template<class Tag>
struct tag_t {};

// helper type to find the "caller" function pointer used to erase invoke:
template<class Sig>
struct caller_type;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct caller_type<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R(*)(void*, Args&&...);
};

template<class Sig>
using caller = typename caller_type<Sig>::type;

// make a caller<Sig> that type erases calling T with Sig:
template<class T, class Sig>
struct make_caller;
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
struct make_caller<T, R(Args...)> {
  caller<R(Args...)> operator()() const {
    return [](void* ptr, Args&&...args)->R {
      return (*static_cast<T*>(ptr))( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    };
  }
};
template<class T, class...Args>
struct make_caller<T, void(Args...)> {
  caller<void(Args...)> operator()() const {
    return [](void* ptr, Args&&...args)->void {
      (*static_cast<T*>(ptr))( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    };
  }
};

// provides operator() overload compatible with Sig,
// then dispatches the call down through a derived type D:
template<class D, class Sig>
struct call_dispatch;

template<class D, class R, class...Args>
struct call_dispatch<D, R(Args...)> {
  R operator()(Args...args)const {\
    auto* caller = self()->get_caller(tag_t<R(Args...)>{});
    return (*caller)( self()->pvoid(), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
  auto self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  auto self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); }
};

// stores a function pointer to invoke Sig
template<class Sig>
struct call_storage {
  caller<Sig> f = nullptr;
  template<class T>
  static call_storage make() {
    return {make_caller<T, Sig>{}()};
  }
  caller<Sig> get_caller( tag_t<Sig> ) const { return f; }
};

// a table of such function pointers
template<class...Sig>
struct call_vtable:call_storage<Sig>... {
  template<class T>
  static call_vtable make() {
    return {call_storage<Sig>::template make<T>()...};
  }
  using call_storage<Sig>::get_caller...;
};

// overload helper to dispatch to correct Sig:
template<class D, class...Sig>
struct call_dispatcher:
  call_dispatch<D, Sig>...
{
  using call_dispatch< D, Sig >::operator()...;
};

// Erases invoking but not storing an arbitrary type T
// with all of ...Sig.  Stores the invokers inside itself,
// not in an external vtable, to increase locality at the cost
// of per-instance size:
template<class... Sig>
struct call_view_t:
  private call_vtable<Sig...>,
  call_dispatcher< call_view_t<Sig...>, Sig... >
{
  template<class F,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, call_view_t>{}, bool> =true
  >
  call_view_t( F&& f ):
    call_vtable<Sig...>( call_vtable<Sig...>::template make<std::decay_t<F>>() ),
    ptr( std::addressof(f) )
  {}        
  call_view_t()=default;
  call_view_t(call_view_t const&)=default;
  call_view_t& operator=(call_view_t const&)=default;
  explicit operator bool() const { return ptr != nullptr; }
  void* pvoid() const { return ptr; }

  using call_vtable<Sig...>::get_caller;
private:
  void* ptr = 0;
};
```

it requires 2 pointers, one to store non-owning state and one to store an invoker (it also supports any number of signatures on the thing to invoke).

We can create a new `call_view` type that instead of storing a `ptr*`, stores a block of memory; in that block, it placement new's the state of the `F` passed in and `pvoid()` returns a pointer to it.

Unless you restrict yourself to trivial destruction and copy/move, you'll also have to store pointers to functions on how to do that.

As `call_impl` only varies based on the **type** of thing stored and not its value, we can store the `f`'s in a vtable and only inherit from `call_dispatch`.  Inside that vtable we can store copy/move/destroy of our copy of `F`.

This permits us to have a trim `std::function` with state that only requires 1 pointer overhead over the storage of whatever state you want to put in the `std::function`.

Note that the above code probably has typos, and doesn't solve your problem.  It has 9/10 of the pieces to solve your problem.

```
// a vtable that represents "I can be copied or moved and destroyed":
struct copyable_vtable {
  void(*dtor)(void*)=0;
  void(*copy)(void* dest, void const* src)=0;
  void(*move)(void* dest, void* src)=0;

  template<class T>
  static copyable_vtable make() {
    return {
      [](void* ptr){ static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T(); },
      [](void* dest, void const* src){
        ::new( dest ) T(*static_cast<T const*>(src));
      },
      [](void* dest, void * src){
        ::new( dest ) T(std::move(*static_cast<T const*>(src)));
      }
    };
  }
};
// the vtable that our "small function" needs:
template<class...Sig>
struct small_func_vtable:
  copyable_vtable,
  call_vtable<Sig...>
{
  template<class T>
  static small_func_vtable make() {
    return {
      copyable_vtable::template make<T>(),
      call_vtable<Sig...>::template make<T>()
    };
  }
  template<class T>
  static small_func_vtable const* get() {
    static const auto vtable = make<T>();
    return &vtable;
  }
};

// bundles up the size and alignment requirements:    
template<std::size_t S=sizeof(void*)*3, std::size_t A=alignof(void*)>
struct size_params {
  enum { size = S, align = A };
};
// A small stack allocated std::function that refuses to get bigger
// If you try to construct it with something larger, you get
// a static assert failure.  Also supports arbitrary number of
// overloads of ():
template<class Size, class...Sig>
struct small_function:
  call_dispatcher< small_function<Size, Sig...>, Sig... >
{
private:
  small_func_vtable<Sig...> const* vtable = 0;
  mutable std::aligned_storage_t< Size::size, Size::align > data;
public:

  template<class F,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, small_function>{}, bool> =true
  >
  small_function( F&& f )
  {
    static_assert( sizeof(std::decay_t<F>)<=Size::size );
    static_assert( alignof(std::decay_t<F>)<=Size::align );
    ::new( (void*)&data ) std::decay_t<F>( std::forward<F>(f) );
    vtable = small_func_vtable<Sig...>::template get<std::decay_t<F>>();
  }
  small_function()=default;

  // we could refactor this into base class:
  small_function(small_function const& o) {
    if (!o.vtable) return;
    o.vtable->copy( pvoid(), o.pvoid() );
    vtable = o.vtable;
  }
  small_function(small_function&& o) {
    if (!o.vtable) return;
    o.vtable->move( pvoid(), o.pvoid() );
    vtable = o.vtable;
  }
  small_function& operator=(small_function const& o) {
    if (this == &o) return *this;
    if (vtable) {
      vtable->dtor(pvoid());
      vtable = nullptr;
    }
    if (o.vtable) {
      o.vtable->copy( pvoid(), o.pvoid() );
      vtable = o.vtable;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  small_function& operator=(small_function&& o) {
    if (this == &o) return *this;
    if (vtable) {
      vtable->dtor(pvoid());
      vtable = nullptr;
    }
    if (o.vtable) {
      o.vtable->move( pvoid(), o.pvoid() );
      vtable = o.vtable;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  // use null vtable to determine if we are empty:
  explicit operator bool() const { return vtable != nullptr; }

  // these must be visible to dispatch system.  I think
  // they are harmless to expose to end users, so I don't bother
  // with making them private and friending dispatch system:
  void* pvoid() const { return &data; }
  template<class S>
  caller<S> get_caller(tag_t<S> t) const {
    if (!vtable) return nullptr;
    return vtable->get_caller(t);
  }
};

template<class...Sig>
using simple_small_function = small_function< size_params<>, Sig... >;
```

and try `simple_small_function`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39bf4b946440931c).

Comment: Looks really scary))

Comment: @Serhiy You asked to replace a low level vocabulary type.  :)  I can do that, but it will be scary.

Comment: I've added to the question my simple implementation with your tip "member to member function", it's much better, it get 24 bytes per member, but still not 16. Could you have a glance to it please.

Comment: @Serhiy Wait, both the TYPE **AND** the class you are operating on is fixed?  Are the member function pointers also fixed at compile time and never change?

Comment: Yes, members are fixed at compile time. Template instantiated with TYPEs as int, bool,QString..
In ideas situation I'll have 3 pointers, to getter func, setter  func and object for them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what we need for [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

1. A pointer for the list of how to copy, destroy, and invoke the payload. Knowledge of the targets type and how to retrieve it is a bonus, and extra cost per type is marginal (none per instance).
2. The target. To avoid rampant allocating, there should be space for at least a member-function-pointer. Unfortunately, the conforming format MSVC uses is a whomping 4 pointers big (they use different smaller non-conforming ones in different situations). Other ABIs use smaller ones for full effect.

So, that's 5 pointers worth => 5*8 = 40 Bytes on 64 bit Windows as a minimum to accomodate member-function-pointers.